# Pointers to Incomplete Types

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, compiler-construction, incomplete-type

Consider the following:

```
class Incomplete;

class Complete
{
    Incomplete* Foo; // Will only compile if Foo is a pointer.
};

class Incomplete
{
    Complete Bar; // Bar can be a pointer or an object.
};
```

How are pointers to incomplete types legal?  How does the compiler know how big an object of type `Incomplete` is?  And since it *can* apparently figure out the size, why are regular objects of incomplete types *illegal?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that pointers to incomplete types are legal is precisely *because* the compiler doesn't need to know their size.

The reason that you cannot declare an object of incomplete type is, as you've mentioned, because the compiler doesn't know how large the object is and therefore can't allocate space for it.  When declaring a *pointer* to an incomplete type, though, the size is known because typically all pointers on a machine have the same size.

Moreover, you don't need to know how large the object is when *declaring* a pointer to an object of incomplete type.  However, if you try *using* an object of incomplete type, such as by following that pointer or trying to instantiate an object of that type, then the compiler will give you an error.

In short, the pointer is legal because it can be created without the compiler knowing the size of what's being pointed at.  If you actually need to know the size or layout of that object by using the pointer, though, the compiler will need to have more information about the type.

Answer (score 4):

The size of a pointer is not dependent on the size of the type it points to. `int*` and `Incomplete*` are of the same size.

For regular objects, however, the size is unknown.

Comment: In addition, allocation will be done at run time, and at that point the size of the object should be known. Since pointers are always the same size, the size of the actual size of the object it is referring to can be determined when the application is executed.

Comment: The allocation code will not compile if the size is unknown, and it is true for the class member object (like the Incomplete::Bar in the example above), or a new dynamic allocation, or allocation on stack. Anywhere where the compiler has to put in the size of the memory chunk required by the object - the compiler will complain if the type is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't need to know how big instance of `Incomplete` is, because pointers are *always* the same size.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the compiler know how big an object of type Incomplete is?

It doesn't. It works with a pointer because the compiler knows the size to allocate **for the pointer**.